# Load div (fade in) step by step

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I make a html page. I want load step by step in page with jQuery but I don't know make it.

My HTML code:

```
<div class="main-template">
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
</div>
```

Fade-in burst in sequence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below:

```js
$(function(){
$('.main-child').hide();
$('div.main-child').each(function(i){
$(this).delay(i*800).fadeIn('slow');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-template">
    <div class="main-child">1</div>
    <div class="main-child">2</div>
    <div class="main-child">3</div>
    <div class="main-child">4</div>
    <div class="main-child">5</div>
    <div class="main-child">6</div>
    <div class="main-child">7</div>
    <div class="main-child">8</div>
    <div class="main-child">9</div>
    <div class="main-child">10</div>
    <div class="main-child">11</div>
    <div class="main-child">12</div>
    <div class="main-child">13</div>
    <div class="main-child">14</div>
    <div class="main-child">15</div>
    <div class="main-child">16</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check this? @Sushiant

Comment: Work it ...  Tank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$('.main-child').each(function(i) {$(this).fadeOut(0).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1850);});`

Here Is [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vDLA7/142/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? We iterate through all the elements with `.each()` and set a `setTimeout()` with a time dependent on the index `i`.

```js
$(".main-child").each(function (i) {
    var element = $(this); 
    setTimeout(function() { 
      element.animate({"opacity": 1}, 500);
    }, 200*i);
  });
```

```css
.main-child{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-template">
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
    <div class="main-child"></div>
</div>
```